# JSON Android skipping try and get the catch message

Tags: android, json, exception

Hi I am trying to write a `log_in` button to my app and this way it worked fine on another app but it did not work on this it shows me the message in the `JSONException` catch

here is my code

```
try {

    JSONObject json=null;
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    for( int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
        json = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Work fine man " + json.getString("name"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       Intent s = new Intent(Sign_in.this, Search.class);
        startActivity(s);

    }
}
catch(JSONException e)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Mail and pass",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
}
```

here is the `result`

```
String result ="";
try{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));  
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null){
        sb.append(line +"\n");
    }
    is.close();
    result=sb.toString();
}
catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "erorr converting result "+e.toString());  
}
```

Comment: How does `result` look like?

Comment: post yout `e.printStackTrace()` please?

Comment: @timrau i have added the result

Comment: @BassemAshry We need the content of `result` when exception happened.

Comment: @timrau it dose not give a log cat error the toast in the catch appear

Comment: You can add Log.e() one line before `Toast.makeText()`.